# About States and what is better for Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Lets assume that I have a job with `max.parallelism=4` and a `RichFlatMapFunction` which is working with `MapState`. What is the best way to create the `MapStateDescriptor`? into the `RichFlatMapFunction` which means that for each instance of this class I will have a descriptor, or create a single instance of the descriptor, for example: `public static MapStateDescriptor descriptor` in a single class and call it from the `RichFlatMapFunction`? Because doing it on this way I will have just one `MapStateDescriptor` instead of 4, or did I misunderstood something?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 2):

A few points...

1. Since each of your `RichFlatMapFunction` sub-tasks can be running in a different JVM on a different server, how would they share a static `MapStateDescriptor`?
2. Note that Flink's "max parallelism" isn't the same as the default environment parallelism. In general you want to leave the max parallelism value alone, and (if necessary) set your environment parallelism equal to the number of slots in your cluster.
3. The `MapStateDescriptor` doesn't store state. It tells Flink how to create the state. In your `RichFlatMapFunction` operator's `open()` call is where you'll be creating the state **using** the state descriptor.

So net-net is don't bother using a static `MapStateDescriptor`, it won't help. Just create your state (as per many examples) in your `open()` method.

Comment: To add: it's really important that you don't share the resulting `MapState` across threads/function instances - it's not thread-safe. Make sure you have a normal instance field per function, such that each task thread has its own `MapState`. For descriptors, it's not uncommon to share them across all threads in one task manager, but it's really not saving much (a few bytes of main memory).

Comment: I'm not sharing a `MapState` across the threads, I have one instance of `MapState` for each subtask, I was wondering about `MapStateDescriptor`, because I only need to declare one to say to my subtasks that has a `MapState` how they will behaves, and for that I'm not sure if I need one `MapStateDescriptor` for each subtask or maybe is better to has just one.

Comment: The state descriptor is only used once (per sub-task), in the `open()` method, so it doesn't matter whether it's a static or not.

Comment: You will declare the state descriptor only once but Flink internally will create different Descriptors for each subtask based on the different keys

Comment: @kkrugler is there a reason the descriptor is instantiated in the `open()` method and not in the field definition? I noticed all the docs do this but have not seen why

Comment: No specific reason why it's instantiated in the `open()` method, other than statics are typically used when you've got multiple references to the same thing. So if you only use it in the open method, you might as well create it in the same method.